# using virtualfields to query associated model

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

i have Transaction model with recieved virtual field based on other model column.

```
$this->Transaction->virtualFields['recieved'] = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transaction_details AS Transaction WHERE Transaction.destination =".$key;
```

now the field is present in the find results but with incorrect value.is any there anything am missing.
P.S: am using associated field Transaction.destination in WHERE clause. is that legal

Comment: Try this SUM(Transaction.amount) instead of SUM(amount)